# Swipe/Drag to dismiss RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewdraghelper

I am looking for a way to dismiss `RecyclerView` when it is scrolled over bounds. Effect would be similar to Google Maps.

I have `RecyclerView` with top padding so scrolling content works visually properly but when I scroll down to `RecyclerView` top I would like to start dragging the whole `RecyclerView` down and eventually hide it.

Is this achievable with `ViewDragHelper` somehow programmatically intercepting the touch and start dragging it, I've been trying to force the drag with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: have you found the answer. because i am stuck with it!